# Unable to Load Large Datasets to Azure Search Index

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to load around 30,000 records in an Azure Cognitive Search index. The source data comes from a Pandas dataframe, and I am attempting to upload it as follows:

```
    file = df.to_dict(orient="records")

    # "Use SearchIndexingBufferedSender to upload the documents in batches optimized for indexing"  
    with SearchIndexingBufferedSender(  
        endpoint=service_endpoint,  
        index_name=index_name,  
        credential=credential,  
    ) as batch_client:  
        # Add upload actions for all documents  
        batch_client.upload_documents(documents=file)  
    print(f"Uploaded {len(file)} documents in total to {index_name}")
```

If I upload up to 1500 documents (after index creation), they load without issues. If I try to load more instead (also after index creation), the index will only contain the first record.

I have noticed that, after uploading those 1500 documents, I can upload another new 1000 - 1500 documents manually (by running the same code), and the index will contain all 3000. However, if I try to upload a second round of more than 1500 documents, it will only upload one new document.

This leads me to think that the index will accept more than 1500 documents (meaning, it is not a problem with size) but the batch upload in the code above is not working correctly; it seems to not be buffering and batching.

I could run the same code manually until I get to those 30,000 records, but I would like to solve the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I’m wondering if this has something to do with the batch size. There’s a limit to the number of documents/batch size when uploading documents in batch.

Comment: @GauravMantri - That is what I am thinking as well. But I have not found a parameter for SearchIndexingBufferedSender to set the number of documents for each batch, and that seems to be the exact purpose of this class. It is also confusing that I have used this code in the past with large numbers of documents (although it has been a while, so maybe it is caused by a version change?) and it worked fine.

Comment: Based on the information provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#document-limits), the limit is 16MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on testing, it seems the maximum allowed limit is just under `64MB size` and `32000 Documents(indexing actions per request)`.

So, the issue might with your data size and to fix this you can chunk your data into batch size less than 64MB.
Below is a sample code for reference:

```py
documents = df.to_dict(orient="records")
# Split the data into chunks 
chunks = [documents[i:i + 10000] for i in range(0, len(documents), 10000)]

# Upload the data
for chunk in chunks:
    with SearchIndexingBufferedSender(service_endpoint, index_name) as batch_client:    
        batch_client.upload_documents(documents=chunk) 
    print(f"Uploaded {len(chunk)} documents")
```

With above code, I was able to upload fix the issue:
[image]

Comment: Splitting in chunks works. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't batching the whole point of the thing?